# Magento Event Observer on Place Order

Tags: magento

Here i am Using an Observer ,when we Place Order for any product it does works

```
<global>
        <events>


    <sales_order_place_after>
                <observers>
                   <Test_Check_Model_Observer>
                      <type>singleton</type>
                      <class>Test_Check_Model_Observer</class>
                      <method>SubscribePlan</method>
                   </Test_Check_Model_Observer>
               </observers>
        </sales_order_place_after>
</events>
</global>
```

and this is my observer method

```
public function SubscribePlan($observer) { 

die('called');
}
```

but when i Place order for recurring profile it doesn't work, is there any solution or alternate for this problem 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Magento has default save event for any model i.e. model_save_after,

so as `Mage::getModel('sales/recurring_profile');` is loaded, you can check for event i.e.

```
recurring_profile_save_after
```

P.S. This is untested, and just a guess on basis of how default implicit events are fired in Magento.

Or else you could put a log in

```
 Mage.php



  public static function dispatchEvent($name, array $data = array())
    {
        Varien_Profiler::start('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
        $result = self::app()->dispatchEvent($name, $data);
        Varien_Profiler::stop('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
        return $result;
    }
```

and check which events are fired, and then try to capture it

Comment: It shows the List of Events, how can i find out which event is getting used for particular page

Comment: when your recurring profile gets saved, you enable it for that time, and then check which events were fired during creation of recurring order.